# I want to disable Time in time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

```js
$(function () {     
    jQuery('#onselectExample').timepicker({
        'minTime': '7:00am',
        'maxTime': '7:00pm',
        //format: 'H:i'
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns left" style="text-align:right;">@Html.Label("Time")</div>
    <div class="large-7 columns left">
        <input id="onselectExample" type="text" class="time"  name="onselectExample" required/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am having a field in my form which is "Time". It is jQuery time picker. I can see the time every half hourly,i have given specific time i.e; from morning 7-am to evening 7-pm.I have taken the time like this as it will be used for giving appointments and in a particular time-slot only 3 customers can get appointment.And,i also want to disable the time,which has gone in the present day and the previous days as well.I don't want to do it with Database.

Comment: Why do you even use the timepicker then? Just put the three choices in a selectbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an mvc approach using a selectbox.  In your view model create a property like

```
public IList<SelectListItem> ScheduleTimes { get; set; }
public string SelectedScheduleTime { get; set; }
```

and for the view model constructor

```
public ViewModel()
{
    ScheduleTimes = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var dt = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0);
    var dtEnd = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 19, 0, 0);
    while (dt <= dtEnd)
    {
        ScheduleTimes.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dt.ToString("hh:mm tt"), Value = dt.ToString("hh:mm tt") });
        dt.AddMinutes(30);
    }
}
```

And for your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedScheduleTime, Model.ScheduleTimes, new {@class = "form-control"})
```